# Change Image format from NHWC to NCHW for Pytorch

Tags: image, deep-learning, permutation, conv-neural-network, pytorch

In pytorch we need images in `NCHW` format but my images are `NHWC`.

What is the procedure to feed this image to CNN? (I have found [this solution](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/swap-axes-in-pytorch/970) which suggests to use "permute" but where and how should i use it?)

Answer (score 15):

Using [`torch.Tensor.permute()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.permute):

```python
 x = x.permute(0, 3, 1, 2) # from NHWC to NCHW
```

Comment: is this equal to np.transpose() ?

Comment: It basically does the same thing, yes (with the PyTorch advantages e.g. GPU support).